# No device with Vulkan support found error on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, vulkan

On my Windows machine I created `C:\Users\<user name>\.android\advancedFeatures.ini` with the following content:

```
Vulkan = on
GLDirectMem = on
```

but when I tried to run an [app using Vulkan](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/tree/master/examples/triangle) on Android 12 emulator I got the following error:

[image]